Is there an R function to draw ellipsoids (or any kind of surrounding) to clusters in 3 dimensions?
Withing R, I would like to make clusters in three dimensions more visible by drawing a semi transparent ellipsoid around them (or encircle them somehow).
Here's an example using R internal iris data set (but without the ellipsoids I am hoping for).
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, z=~Petal.Length, color = ~Species)


Thanks in advance :)

There is a guide for how to do exactly that but in python though: https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-point-clustering/

Thanks sactyr. I also saw a nice post on visualizing 3d convex hulls here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78019259/visualizing-3d-convex-hulls-for-grouped-data-in-r-with-plotly. But for larger data sets it throws some errors.

I used the python guide I linked in the comments, then played around with the settings. While this solution doesn't quite draw ellipsoids, it does show the clusters a bit better. I found setting the alphahull parameter high to give better distinction of the clusters, you may want to experiment with this.
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  iris
  , x=~Sepal.Width
  , y=~Sepal.Length
  , z=~Petal.Length
  , alphahull = 9
  , opacity = 0.1
  , type = "mesh3d"
  , color = ~Species
)



